# How to implement strategy pattern in C++ with std::function

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, strategy-pattern, std-function

I'm reasing about the best way to implement the strategy pattern in C++. Up to now, I've always used the standard way, where the context has a pointer to the base strategy class as follows:

```cpp
 class AbstractStrategy{
 public:
     virtual void exec() = 0;
 }
 class ConcreteStrategyA{
 public:
     void exec();
 }
 class ConcreteStrategyB{
 public:
     void exec();
 }

 class Context{
 public:
     Context(AbstractStrategy* strategy):strategy_(strategy){}
     ~Context(){
          delete strategy;
       }
      void run(){
           strategy->exec();
      }
 private:
     AbstractStrategy* strategy_;
```

Since having pointers to objects can result in bad behavior, I was looking for a safer way to implement this pattern and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364689/should-safe-pointers-be-used-in-strategy-pattern) where `std::function` are proposed as a better way to handle this pattern.

Could someone please explain better how `std::function` works, maybe with an example with the strategy pattern?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that single-method objects are isomorphic to functions, and strategies are just single-method objects.

So basically, you get rid of all your classes, and you just use `std::function<void()>` instead:

```
class Context {
public:
    template<typename F>
    explicit Context(F strategy) : strategy(std::move(strategy)) { }

    void run() { strategy(); }

private:
    std::function<void()> strategy;
};
```

Then you can pass any callable to the constructor of `Context`:

```
Context ctx([] { std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; });
ctx.run();
```

Comment: In this case, how would you implement F (the strategy)? And why you need to use std::move?

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh The strategy is just any function pointer or object with `operator()` overloaded. My example passes a lambda (which defines `void operator()() const`). `std::move` is to prevent a copy.

Answer (score 5):

There's a bit of a discussion of this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352936/why-do-we-use-stdfunction-in-c-rather-than-the-original-c-function-pointer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054774/difference-between-stdfunction-and-a-standard-function-pointer). I think it depends on the particular case at hand. Is your strategy a simple function call only, for instance - I often have strategy patterns in which my strategy will need multiple capabilities, which isn't handled well by just having a function or functor. But if you do need just a function or functor, then `std::function` is a handy way to allow ultimate flexibility, storing function pointers, lambdas or functors. There can be performance issues, which were discussed [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/function/faq.html#id1284915) for the original boost implementation.

Comment: What would you suggest in the case where the strategy is not simple a function call? In that case a pointer to an abstract class is the only way?

Comment: Yes. You can handle proper resource control with `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Working on the answer of райтфолд

Basically, you get rid of all your classes, and you just use std::function instead.

This generalized function allows you to pass functions, lambda, functors, and member functions (using std::bind)

```
class Context {
public:
   explicit Context(std::function<void()> input) : strategy(input) { }

void run() { strategy(); }

private:
   std::function<void()> strategy;
};
```

Then you can pass any callable to the constructor of Context:

```
Context ctx([] { std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; });
ctx.run();
```

or

```
void sayHelloWorld(){
   std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}


int main(){
   Context ctx( sayHelloWorld );
   ctx.run();  
}
```

or

```
class SayHelloWorld{
   operator()(){std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";}
}

int main(){
   SayHelloWorld hello_world;
   Context ctx( hello_world );
   ctx.run();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


typedef std::function<int(int)> Strategy;

void execute_strategy(Strategy strategy, int object) {
    std::cout << strategy(object) << std::endl;
};

int power2(int i) {
    return i*i;
};

int main() {
    execute_strategy(power2, 3);
}
```

I mean, strategy pattern is a solution for the shortcoming of not having actual lambdas. That's resolved, so you could just pass the appropriate function around.